# How to avoid TextView.getLayout() to return null?

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView that the getLayout returns null.
Which is "normal" according the documentation, because just before, I addded it to a layout, then it changes its width.

how to avoid this?

(i tried with a OnGlobalLayoutListener, then waiting it has its full width,  but it does not always work)

EDIT:
I call from an list adapter, in the getView():

```
drawArticle(article, true);
```

Here is the drawArticle() method:

```
TextView txt;
Spanned text;
private void drawArticle(final Article article, boolean first) {
    if(first){
        text = Html.fromHtml(article.content);
    } else {
        text = Html.fromHtml(getInvisibleText(txt));
    }
    txt = createTextView();

    txt.setText(text);
    layout.addView(txt);
    vto = txt.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            txt.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            String inVisibleText = getInvisibleText(txt);
            if (inVisibleText != null && !inVisibleText.isEmpty()) {
                drawArticle(article, false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and

```
private String getInvisibleText(final TextView textView) {
    Layout staticLayout = null;
    String toDislay = "";
    int height    = textView.getHeight();
    int scrollY   = textView.getScrollY();
    staticLayout = textView.getLayout();
    int lastVisibleLineNumber  = staticLayout.getLineForVertical(scrollY+height);
    int start = staticLayout.getLineEnd(lastVisibleLineNumber);
    int end = staticLayout.getLineEnd(textView.getLineCount()-1);
    toDislay = textView.getText().toString().substring(start, end);
    return toDislay;
}
```

This is suppose to set a very long text into a text view, then get what is not displayed to recursively put in other textviews

Comment: code pls...dont make us round round :)

Comment: " but it does not always work".  OnGlobalLayoutListener always works, therefore the problem is your code.  Please show us.

Comment: yes, what I meant is that MY code inside does not give what I would expect, of course OnGlobalLayoutListener always works ;)
I'll edit

Comment: in fact in the first iteration the getLayout is not null, can I save it and then use the very same TextView.layout accross others textviews calculus?

Comment: FYI, it is possible for getLayout to return null inside onGlobalLayout().